# Use window.open but block use of window.opener

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

A while back I ran across an [interesting security hole](https://dev.to/ben/the-targetblank-vulnerability-by-example)

```
<a href="http://someurl.here" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Looks innocuous enough, but there's a hole because, by default, the page that's being opened is allowing the opened page to call back into it via `window.opener`. There are some restrictions, being cross-domain, but there's still some mischief that can be done

```
window.opener.location = 'http://gotcha.badstuff';
```

Now, HTML has a workaround

```
<a href="http://someurl.here" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link</a>
```

That prevents the new window from having `window.opener` passed to it. That's fine and good for HTML, but what if you're using `window.open`?

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://someurl.here', '_blank');">
    Click Me
</button>
```

How would you block the use of `window.opener` being passed here?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `window.open()` call now [supports](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name:disowned-its-opener) the feature "noopener". 

 So calling `window.open('https://www.your.url','_blank','noopener')` *should* open the new window/tab with a null `window.opener`.

I'm having trouble finding a reliable list of supporting browsers (and versions) - MDN states [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#noopener) that

> This is supported in modern browsers including Chrome, and Firefox 52+.

From my experimentation, I see it works for:

- **Chrome** 61
- **FireFox** 56
- **Safari** 11.1 (thanks [Jiayi Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6860493/jiayi-hu) for this)

But doesn't work for:

- **IE** 11.608
- **Edge** 40

(All tests on a PC running Windows 10...)

For backwards compatibility it may be better to combine this with [t3__rry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40593743/3892498).

Comment: If anybody tests this on additional browsers/OSs, feel free to comment or suggest an edit - it'll be nice to have a more complete picture of the support for this feature

Comment: Wait, actually it does work -- but it doesn't open it in a tab. Its a new window with no frame. Pretty bizarre. Try it in your console.

Comment: @Chet on what version of Chrome do you see that behavior?

Comment: I'm using version 62.0.3202.94

Comment: @Chet As mentioned in the Chrome issue, you can do  window.open(url,'_blank','toolbar=1,menubar=1,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,noopener') as a workaround to get it to open in a tab. 

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596068#c15

Answer (score 34):

Use

```
var yourWindow = window.open();
yourWindow.opener = null;
yourWindow.location = "http://someurl.here";
```

Credit goes to Mathias Bynens: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

Comment: As noted in the linked article, this method may trigger the pop-up blocker of the browser. I just tried the code, and indeed, yellow bar "Firefox prevented this site from opening a pop-up window."

Comment: Mod note: do not introduce edits that are a commentary to the post.

Comment: you still need to do this in Safari for the above to work properly:  
`Note that the JavaScript-based work-around fails in Safari. For Safari support, inject a hidden iframe that opens the new tab, and then immediately remove the iframe.`

Comment: Works for me in Firefox but not in Chrome 86 where a popup is opened but the site isn't loaded. Chrome error message: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to 'https://google.com'.`  Reversing the last two lines work but not sure if it affects security.

Answer (score 19):

Pointing out that it's a comma separated list of features (no whitespaces), so you could set `'noopener,noreferrer,resizable'` i.e.:

```
window.open('http://sensible.url', '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer,resizable')
```

From [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> `windowFeatures` *Optional*
>
> A DOMString containing a comma-separated list of window features given with their corresponding values in the form "name=value". [...]

Comment: One small question - the documentation states use in the form name=value. So wouldn't it instead be 'noopner=<boolean>". Not sure if that should be true or false.

Comment: @AshD you can see in the [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#toolbar_and_ui_parts_features) that toolbars and UI parts are key-value features, `status=yes, status=1, and status have identical results.`, but `noopener` and `noreferrer` are functional features so they exist or don't exist, but with no extra value

Answer (score 10):

According to the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/open), in the following code

```
window.open('https://www.your.url','_blank','noopener')
```

The third argument contains the "WindowFeatures" (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features) so it makes sense that it opens the target in a new window

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
const a = document.createElement("a")
a.href = args.url
a.target = "_blank"
a.rel = "noopener"
a.click()
```

Comment: All you're doing is creating an anchor tag with JS DOM, which does the same thing as the HTML in the question. You're not using `window.open`, which is why I asked this

Comment: I see. I thought you're goal was just the functionality.

Comment: this way works cross-browser and it is achieving the same functionality as using `window.open`. Both functionalities are ultimately using JavaScript whereas the question is purely surrounding HTML markup.

Comment: This seems to be the most reliable method for cross browser support.

Comment: But this may not return an object for you to check if the popup succeeded or not. This may be useful if your page is under a sandboxed iFrame that doesn't allow popups.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: `target="_blank"` implying `rel="noopener"` behavior has been proposed in [#4078](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4078) and fixed in [PR#4330](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/4330) on 31.01.2019

Most modern browsers have incorporated this change, but mostly those are the newest versions. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#browser_compatibility

Comment: This only has an effect on `<a>` elements. I tried this in Chrome 99 and I'm still able to access `window.opener` when windows are opened via `window.open(url, "_blank")`