# When should I use rel=noreferrer?

Tags: html, hyperlink, rel

I have to link some other external sites.

I know when to use `nofollow`. But I am not clear when I should use `rel=noreferrer`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In short, the **`noreferrer` link type hides referrer information when the link is clicked**. A link with the `noreferrer` link type looks something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="noreferrer">Click here for more info</a>
```

If someone arrives at your site from a link that uses this link type, your analytics won't show who refered that link. Instead, it will mistakenly show as direct traffic in your acquisition channels report.

**If you have an external link to someone else's site you don't trust and you want to hide referrer information then you can combine both and use**

```
<a href="http://example.com/sample_page/" rel="noreferrer nofollow">Other Domain Link</a>
```

I advise you to use `nofollow` links for the following content:

- **Links in comments or on forums** - Anything that has user-generated content is likely to be a source of spam. Even if you carefully moderate, things will slip through.
- **Advertisements & sponsored links** - Any links that are meant to be advertisements or are part of a sponsorship arrangement must be nofollowed.
- **Paid links** - If you charge in any way for a link (directory submission, quality assessment, reviews, etc.), `nofollow` the outbound links

Comment: It seems rare that you would "link to [a] site you don't trust"

Comment: @A.K. The usual case is user generated content, that you don't know whether or not is trustworthy. But any external site could itself be a victim of a hack, so best practice is to be safe.

Comment: @Aaron Any site that isn't yours is one you shouldn't trust.

Answer (score 15):

`noreferrer` doesn't just block the HTTP referrer header, it also prevents a [Javascript exploit involving window.opener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593632/use-window-open-but-block-use-of-window-opener)

> `<a href="http://someurl.here" target="_blank">Link</a>`
>    Looks innocuous enough, but there's a hole because, by default, the page that's being opened is allowing the opened page to call back into it via window.opener. There are some restrictions, being cross-domain, but there's still some mischief that can be done
>   `window.opener.location = 'http://gotcha.badstuff';`

With `noreferrer` most browsers will disallow the `window.opener` exploit

Comment: I believe noopener is the current best practice to handle that exploit, not noreferrer.

Answer (score 5):

As @unor said, it hides referrer information when the link is clicked. Basically this is a privacy enhancement for when you want to hide from the owner of the linked domain that the user came from your website.

Example:

User is on your website **[www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)**, there you have a `<a href="https://newsite.com">Link</a>`. When someone clicks the "Link" the owner of **newsite.com** knows it came from **[www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)**. By setting `rel=noreferrer` you prevent revealing this information.

A good example how it works is starting from [21:28 of this conference talk](https://youtu.be/TNlcoYLIGFk?t=1288). This is considered to be a [good practice](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/security/secureheaders.md#referrer-policy) when working with server-side (e.g. Node.js). You can also read about this on the [Helmet documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20200414213512/https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/referrer-policy/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll only need to use this on private pages or pages you don't want to advertise. E.g. a webmail or private bug tracker would be considered private and you don't want to [leak any information](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/private-bts-referrer-header.html) to the external linked websites.

Sensitive public pages, like medical information or other sensitive topics may also want to mask the referrer header.