# Is using rel="noreferrer" mandatory If users are redirected to my website home page to another page (same website) using target="_blank"?

Tags: html

I came to know about the usage of the `rel=noreferrer` attribute when using a `target = _blank` to an external website. But I am using `target = _blank` to my internal website. So is that mandatory? Because web performance report is showing to use it. I have already checked a possible solution but that's for external website not internal.

Comment: I hope this helps! https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773254/7994074

Comment: Thank you for the link, I read this before posting this query, it talks about the external site. Needed help with the internal site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use rel=noreferrer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773152/when-should-i-use-rel-noreferrer)

Comment: Please read my last comment above yours.