# what risks can I avoid by using noreferrer in react links?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-dom

I got this warning on terminal when I was developing a react app. What does it mean? what risks should I expect?

**code**

```
Go to <a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com"> Facebook</a>
```

**Warning**

```
Line 11:21:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank
```

I had to add the specification but I don't know why it important.

```
Go to <a target="_blank"  rel="noreferrer" href="http://facebook.com"> Facebook</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773152/when-should-i-use-rel-noreferrer

Comment: yes it does. thanks

Comment: Ok, yeah, I didn't want to mark your question as a duplicate if it wasn't quite the same question.

Comment: It's not quite duplicate. But I do get the answer I wanted from the link you shared. Thanks D