# target="_blank" not working on some mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

This has me really stymied - I am writing some HTML to a page using jQuery. Within that HTML is a basic link:

```
<a href="http://someurl.com" target="_blank" class="external-link">Link Text</a>
```

The issue is that for some reason, on certain mobile devices (Google Pixel and some iPhones), the link will NOT open in a new tab (either Chrome or Safari). So I tried doing it with JavaScript, using a click event on .external-link - same issue. It just opens in the same browser window on these problematic devices (works fine on mine).

I have confirmed that either way (target="_blank" or JS) *does* work on other multiple devices, including my Android phone. There are no settings that I can see in Chrome/Safari on these devices where it is not working that would be causing this behavior.

Any guesses as to the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that these devices haven't disabled popup windows?

Comment: Popups are disabled - my understanding is that the setting only applies to popup *ads* not to a link opening a new tab. 

I have popups disabled on my phone as well, and the link is working as expected.

Comment: Try and enable the popups and then test again. I once had the same problem and it was that popups was disabled. That setting work different from browser to browser.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers `about:blank` as target should do the trick.
Used it as target for `window.open` in 2018 or in the end of 2017 for Desktop/Mobile/WebView app (probably `_blank` didn't work as expected across browsers back then).
Clarifications about spec or browser source code according to which it works and compatibility table link are welcome.

**Edit 01 Feb. 2021**: Major browsers and weird edge cases. `window.open` fully hangs Firefox on some devices.

```js
// common mobile browsers
var link    =   document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener noreferrer');
link.setAttribute('target', 'about:blank');
link.setAttribute('href', query);
link.click();
```

```js
// other custom browsers
// noopener,noreferrer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46958731/6357894
window.open(query, 'about:blank', 'noopener');
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you can  try:

In case it's not just a typo in the post, make sure you're using target="_blank" instead of target="blank". The underscore is required for the keyword.

If you're linking to a website that you don't own, you should also include rel="noopener". That may not solve this problem on its own, but it's good practice

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that is a typo - it's correct in my code. Adding rel="noopener" seems to make no difference.