# Window.close not working for rel="noreferrer" but works with rel="opener"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Recently, at work, i made a redirection to another site. The maintainers of the other site contacted me and told me that their `window.close` are not working anymore.
Here is a simple explanation of the problem:

let's say site A has an `<a href="http://siteB" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">` tag to navigate to the home page of site B.
In the home page of site B, when you use `window.close()`, the window is closed. Now,(still in the site B), when the user navigates to another page (let's say `/about` page), a `window.close` in this page will not work. Chrome shows this warning:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

But in the `<a>` tag, when i replaced `rel="noreferrer"` by `rel="opener"`, window.close works in any page of the site B.
For `rel="noreferrer"`, `window.close` only works in the first page of the redirection.
If i understand well the warning message, it's because the `/about` page was not opened by the site A, that's why `window.close` will not work in that page. But my question is, why by just changing `rel="noreferrer"` to `rel="opener"`, `window.close` now works everywhere in site B?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593632/use-window-open-but-block-use-of-window-opener

Answer (score 4):

In [documentation of rel in mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel) there's saying `rel="noopener"` or `rel="noreferrer"`

> Creates a top-level browsing context that is not an auxiliary browsing
> context.

The window opened like that has a top-level context.

But for `rel="opener"`

> Creates an auxiliary browsing context.

It means it's not a top-level.

And now for [documentation of `window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) there is

> This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

So for closing window by `close()` function the window shouldn't has top-level context.

Comment: Thanks Fatima. Yours quotes for rel="opener" and rel="noreferrer" helped me  to understand better. In the html specs (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-window-close), there is this paragraph: 
"A browsing context is script-closable if it is an auxiliary browsing context that was created by a script (as opposed to by an action of the user), or if it is a top-level browsing context whose session history contains only one Document." It know make sense when i read your answer.